# Spock definitions starting with caps letter are considered as groovy methods and shown as bug in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, spock

The defs defined in spock such as 
def "Login and Move to checkout page"(){
}

SonarQube considered it as groovy method and shows as bug that the method name should start with small l and not capital L [Login and Move....}

Could you please somebody help in customize sonar rule so that it ignores spock method

Answer (score 0):

If it is not required on your project you may exclude Spock tests from Sonar analyzing at all:

```
sonar.exclusions=src/test/*.groovy
```

Otherwise you should probably find the corresponding rule and change the default regular expression, e.g. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`. But I am not sure you can do this specifically only for groovy test files.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the Sonarqube to ignore Sonar's rule "Method name" for folder where Geb spock scripts are present

It works fine

To know how to configure,follow below steps:

```
1.Goto Administration tab->Analysis Scope->Issues
2.There , you will find "Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria".
3.Provide Rule ID in "Rule Key pattern" textbox [Rule ID can be found by clicking on the particular rule and find it in top right
corner]
4.Provide Filepath for which you need to ignore rule in "File Path Pattern" textbox
5.Click on Save Issues settings
```

Refer below images to know where to see the rule name and where to configure the path
[image: Image to know where Rule ID will be present in the page]
[image: Image where Rule key pattern and File Key pattern text boxes are present]